# Cache MySQL DB with Apache Ignite

Tags: java, mysql, ignite, gridgain

I have some application written in JAVA.
We are using MySQL DB.
It is possible to integrate that MySQL DB with Apache Ignite as In Memory cache and use that configuration without any updates in JAVA application (of course some DB connection details should be changed)?

So my application do the same staff but only difference will be connection with Apache Ignite instead of MySQL?

It is possible this kind of configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are looking for the [write-through](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/persistence/external-storage) feature. I'm not sure what is your use case, but you should be aware of some [limitations](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/persistence/external-storage#read-through-and-write-through) like your data have to be preloaded into Ignite before running SELECT queries. From a very abstract perspective, you need to define POJOs and implement a custom CacheStore interface. Though GridGain Control Center can do the latter for you automatically, check [this demo](https://github.com/GridGain-Demos/ignite-mysql-acceleration-demo) as a reference.